# Another basic question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have 2 tabs in tab bar controller.

tab 1 is the rootController. tab 2 is a tableviewcontroller which gets user information (like signing up)

**What happens now:**

Tab 1 appears first, and I need to click on tab 2 .

**What I need:**

When I open the app, I want the app to start off with Tab 2 (if there are no users in the app ). This should be the very first screen. And then onwards (if there is an user) it should work with tab 1 as the root controller, and the 1st screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;` or `tabBarController.selectedViewController = loginViewController;`

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`,

```
if ( [users count] > 0 ) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
} else {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

This assumes that `users` holds all your users information. Seva's suggestion for using modal view controller is definitely a better approach to deal with `Login`'s. If by users you mean profiles, then this isn't a bad approach either.

Comment: In my ApplicationDelegate, I have set my UITabBarController *rootController, and I have added it to the subbview as [_window addSubview:rootController.view]; Should I be doing rootController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; ??

Comment: Well. assigning     self.rootController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; still seems to bring the first tab first

Comment: FML. Thanks buddy. Working :D

Comment: Okay so, Do you think I can program to hide all the other tabs when [users count] =0  ? So when the app is newly launched the user has no other option but to use tab 2 to enter details before getting other tabs...  ?

Comment: You should look at `setViewControllers:animated:`. Start with only one view controller in the tab and when the user has entered the details, use that method to set the view controllers.

Comment: [_window setViewControllers:myProfileViewController animate:YES]; ?

Comment: No it's a `UITabBarController` method. Use it on `rootViewController`.

Comment: I see. Oh you mean rootController ?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Your "Examples" (sample code) is the ultimate guide !!

Comment: I think it would have been super useful had I started the app with this sort of logic. Now I need to think of a way to use this idea in the existing infrastructure that I dont mess things up...

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want the user to be able to switch to the root tab without completing the login? The tab UI suggests that the tabs are more or less functionally independent of one another; for a required login, a modal view controller is a better metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could check for users is the do something like this:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime"])
{
    //login view show
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];
}
```

Or if you are using a database, you could have a query and then do something based on that.

But I agree w/ Seva, you might want to show the view some other way that doesn't let the user jump views before they are done doing the sign in.